# QThread - changing data in global list - different values

Tags: locking, pyqt5, qthread

I am using QThread to do some time intensive calculations to keep GUI from freezing. In the QThread I am accessing and changing global lists many times during the thread life span, however I am unable to get the same result as if it were just on the main thread.

I would assume you had to perform some kind of lock, but i'm new to QThread and don't know how to implement it.

```
#Main Thread
                    self.runGasAnalysisThread = GasAnalysisThread()
                    self.runGasAnalysisThread.start()

#QThread
class GasAnalysisThread(QtCore.QThread):
    """Performs gas analysis function"""
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        try:
            boolValue = True
            while True:
               #Change lists here
               float(Data.TestList[0])+ 1 #Data is another module I am using to store variables
```

Again, moving the code to the main thread works correctly, but as soon as I do it with QThread I get different results.

How would I implement a locking mechanism to keep this from happening?

Comment: I think I solved my problem, in the QThread I was accesing an array from the main class, and I didn't pass them as parameters to the QThread, as soon as I did it, it worked correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is common to be confused while using Qt's threading, as one would think that subclassing QThread would be the right path.
Truth is that a QThread is the Qt thread object where your process is actually run, which means that you'll need a separate class for it and *move* its instance *in* a QThread. Subclassing QThread is usually unnecessary.
If you need any kind of interaction between the "worker" (the object that does the processing) and the main thread (as in the GUI), it's good practice to use Qt's signals.

In this example I'm using a button to start the processing, once the processor is started it disables the button, and re-enables it once it signals that the process has finished.

```
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    stateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        self.stateChanged.emit(True)
        try:
            boolValue = True
            while True:
               # this doesn't make much sense, as it doesn't seem to do anything;
               # I'll leave it just for the sake of the argument
               float(Data.TestList[0]) + 1
        except:
            pass
        self.stateChanged.emit(False)

class SomeWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.workerThread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
        self.workerThread.started.connect(self.worker.run)

        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.workerThread.start)
        self.worker.stateChanged.connect(self.startButton.setDisabled)
```

Comment: @JohnHennig Yes, but it also adds other useful insight in the next 2 paragraphs (I won't paste them here).
As usual, it always depends on what you need, and understanding what actually "is" a QThread might be confusing - as all the interaction between different threads, signals and slots. Have a look at this (old, but I think still reliable): https://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html expecially the part titled "When to subclass and when not to?". Also, from certain conceptual points of view, keeping the processor separated from the thread is better.